# Return ID from django template language

Tags: html, django

HTML (django template language)

```
{%  if todo_array %}
<ul>
{% for TodoList in todo_array  %}
    <li class="listItems" name="listItem" id="item{{ forloop.counter }}">
        {{ TodoList.todo_text }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p> Add some Todo's !! </p>
{% endif %}
```

I want to return the ID of the list objects on click. How can I do this?

Comment: you can add an Ajax call  on item click

Comment: Return it to what?

Comment: I want to be able to delete the items when clicking on them. I'm trying to get the ID for the items I clicked so I can use it to delete the data from my database. I'm returning it to a .py file